# Example of a factorial time algorithm O( n! )

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, factorial

I'm studying time complexity in school and our main focus seems to be on *polynomial time* `O(n^c)` algorithms and *quasi-linear time* `O(nlog(n))` algorithms with the occasional *exponential time* `O(c^n)` algorithm as an example of run-time perspective. However, dealing with larger time complexities was never covered.

I would like to see an example problem with an algorithmic solution that runs in *factorial time* `O(n!)`. The algorithm may be a naive approach to solve a problem but cannot be artificially bloated to run in factorial time.

Extra street-cred if the factorial time algorithm is the best known algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: Finding all possible paths from source to destination in a directed acyclic graph ([DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### Generate all the permutations of a list

You have `n!` lists, so you cannot achieve better efficiency than `O(n!)`.

Comment: @ziyao-wei Listing all combinations of a set is 2^n. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations_for_all_k . Perhaps you mean listing all permutations? i.e. given n items, how many ways can they be ordered/permuted in an n-length string?

Comment: @ChaimKut: Weird, I sure meant permutations but the asker changed it into combinations, as per edit history. Reverting.

Comment: This actually can be no better than `O(n * n!)` because you have `n!` lists and each one has `n` things in it.

Answer (score 33):

[Traveling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) has a naive solution that's O(n!), but it has a dynamic programming solution that's O(n^2 * 2^n)

Answer (score 10):

List all permutations of an array is O(n!). Below is a recursive implementation using the swap method. The recursion is inside the for loop and the elements in the array are swapped in position until no more elements remain. As you can see from the result count, the number of elements in the array is n!. Each permutation is an operation and there are n! operations.

```
def permutation(array, start, result)
    if (start == array.length) then
        result << array.dup  
    end
    for i in start..array.length-1 do
        array[start], array[i] = array[i], array[start]
        permutation(array, start+1,result)
        array[start], array[i] = array[i], array[start]
    end 
    result   
end        


p permutation([1,2,3], 0, []).count  #> 6 = 3!
p permutation([1,2,3,4], 0, []).count #> 24 = 4!
p permutation([1,2,3,4,5], 0, []).count #> 120 = 5!
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple example with Big O( n! ):

This is in python 3.4

```
 def factorial(n):
    for each in range(n):
        print(n)
        factorial(n-1)
```