# Escaping two lists in Python

Tags: python

So basically I have a really typical issue, I found some solutions from stackoverflow before but this didn't really help me.

I have a school task which requires me to analyze bobsleigh team. I have names, their rating and weight in three separate lists and i need to pick four competitors with best ratings and their weight combined must not be over 325 kg. What I've already done is I've created a `for` cycle which picks out four competitors with highest rating, but the issue is that they may have high ratings but their weight combined is over 325 kg.
For example I have three lists:

```
["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8"] ## names
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ##ratings
[50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120] ##weights
```

what I get is `[5,6,7,8]` (and every single one of them has a according weight list and name list, for example for rating 5 goes competitor with weight of 90 kg and name is Name 5) but their weight combined is higher than 325kg (90+100+110+120 >      325)

I've done coding so far that the minimal element (5) is removed and replaced by another, lower element, but the issue occurs (by issue I mean I don't know how to do it) when switching the last element is not enough and I need to try to replace element 6 and keep the element 5 in place.

Right now the code for switching is:

```
while (kaalude_summa > 325): #if weight is over 325 kg
    positsioon = reiting.index(max(reiting)) #position for max rating
    if kaalud[positsioon] < kaalude_tulemused[3]: #two lists - one is for elements not in the resulting list (kaalud) and one is for the elements in resulting list (kaalude_tulemused)
        kaalude_tulemused[3] = kaalud[positsioon] #sets new weight in result list
        tulemuslist.remove(min(tulemuslist)) #removes number 5 from example list [5,6,7,8] (check above)
        tulemuslist.append(max(reiting)) #adds number 4 from example list
        kaalude_summa = kaalude_summa - vahekaal + kaalude_tulemused[3] #new calculated weight
    reiting.remove(max(reiting)) #removes element from list [1,2,3,4]
    kaalud.remove(kaalud[positsioon])
```

This works as long as the competitors with rating 1,2,3 or 4 weight + other three weights (6,7,8) isn't bigger than 325.

I understand this could be done somehow with two for loops but I tried three times and failed miserably.

It is compulsory to write code in Estonian in our school so I apologize for not writing in English.

I really hope that what I wrote is readable and you are able to help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1JPKqUbh added the whole code into pastebin if my explanation about what happens isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

a brute force approach would be to find all possible combinations of 4 sledders. for each one, find their combined weights and throw away those that exceed 325. of the remaining ones, select the one with the highest ratings.

Comment: It is an option but unfortunately we're not allowed to go with this brute force and the code has to work in normal timeframe so two loops are better i guess.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this thing we're studying in English, but it's something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555978/example-of-a-factorial-time-algorithm-o-n
and it has to be exponential (cˇn)

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve this is to put more while-s after. Although IT is still breakable, but it will check for elements in every position.

```
while (kaalude_summa > 325): #AGA KUI JUHTUB SEE NALI, ET MAX REITINGUD LIIDETAKSE JA IKKA ON PAKSUD
    if reiting == []:
        break
    positsioon = reiting.index(max(reiting)) #max reitingu positsioon
    if kaalud[positsioon] < kaalude_tulemused[3]: 
        kaalude_tulemused[3] = kaalud[positsioon]
        tulemuslist.remove(min(tulemuslist))
        tulemuslist.append(max(reiting))
        kaalude_summa = kaalude_summa - vahekaal + kaalude_tulemused[3]
    reiting.remove(max(reiting))
    kaalud.remove(kaalud[positsioon])

if kaalude_summa > 325:
    reiting = reiting_safecopy[0:len(reiting_safecopy)]
    tulemuslist = tulemuslist_safecopy[0:len(tulemuslist_safecopy)]
    kaalud = kaalud_safecopy[0:len(kaalud_safecopy)]

while (kaalude_summa > 325): #KUI ESIMENE WHILE EI AIDANUD
    if reiting == []:
        break
    positsioon = reiting.index(max(reiting)) #max reitingu positsioon
    if kaalud[positsioon] < kaalude_tulemused[2]: 
        kaalude_tulemused[2] = kaalud[positsioon]
        tulemuslist.remove(min(tulemuslist))
        tulemuslist.append(max(reiting))
        kaalude_summa = kaalude_summa - vahekaal + kaalude_tulemused[3]
    reiting.remove(max(reiting))
    kaalud.remove(kaalud[positsioon])

if kaalude_summa > 325:
    reiting = reiting_safecopy[0:len(reiting_safecopy)]
    tulemuslist = tulemuslist_safecopy[0:len(tulemuslist_safecopy)]
    kaalud = kaalud_safecopy[0:len(kaalud_safecopy)]

while (kaalude_summa > 325): #KUI TEINE WHILE KA EI AIDANUD
    if reiting == []:
        break
    positsioon = reiting.index(max(reiting)) #max reitingu positsioon
    if kaalud[positsioon] < kaalude_tulemused[1]: 
        kaalude_tulemused[1] = kaalud[positsioon]
        tulemuslist.remove(min(tulemuslist))
        tulemuslist.append(max(reiting))
        kaalude_summa = kaalude_summa - vahekaal + kaalude_tulemused[3]

    reiting.remove(max(reiting))
    kaalud.remove(kaalud[positsioon])

if kaalude_summa > 325:
    reiting = reiting_safecopy[0:len(reiting_safecopy)]
    tulemuslist = tulemuslist_safecopy[0:len(tulemuslist_safecopy)]
    kaalud = kaalud_safecopy[0:len(kaalud_safecopy)]

while (kaalude_summa > 325): #SIIS VAHETAME VIIMAST ELEMENTI!!
    if reiting == []:
        break
    positsioon = reiting.index(max(reiting)) #max reitingu positsioon
    if kaalud[positsioon] < kaalude_tulemused[0]: 
        kaalude_tulemused[0] = kaalud[positsioon]
        tulemuslist.remove(min(tulemuslist))
        tulemuslist.append(max(reiting))
        kaalude_summa = kaalude_summa - vahekaal + kaalude_tulemused[3]

    reiting.remove(max(reiting))
    kaalud.remove(kaalud[positsioon])
```